# How do I display individual date display nodes of a commerce event with recurring dates?

Tags: commerce, datetime

I have created a commerce product type for a class that occurs every Monday for 10 weeks. I have the 10 dates displaying in a Calendar view using a start date and a repeat rule. What I can't figure out is how to create display nodes for the individual dates so I can add a recording of the class after it has occurred...possibly required reading beforehand; anyway, is there a way to display individual nodes in this context?

Answer (score 0):

Repeating Dates in Calendar are single nodes that store all the occurances of the event, so for this to work you may have to create single events instead of one that is repeated. Good reading on that issue found here: http://drupal.org/node/298334

Comment: Thanks for suggested reading. It had already occurred to me that individual nodes were what I needed; I didn't realize the complexities. Also sorry to see the discussion slow down as there seemed to be considerable interest. Going to give node_recur a look.